# How to cancel the selected file before upload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

How to cancel the selected file? Before uploading？ Cancel before uploading. Not in the upload process .

*my code:*

```
$('#cancelBtn').click(function (e) {
                     data.abort();
  });
```

but *after* clicking start upload, the canceled file will still be uploaded.

```
    <input id="uploadImg" style="display: none" type="file" name="files[]">
    <button type="button" id="check_file" class="btn btn-primary">Select Files</button> 
    <button type="button" id="upload_file_start" class="btn btn-success">Start upload</button> 
    <button type="button" id="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-default CancelButton">cancel</button>
```

js (jquery)

```
$(function() {
    $("#check_file").on("click", function() {
        $("#uploadImg").click();
    });
    $('#uploadImg').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        sequentialUploads: true,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        done: function(e, data) {
            $('#files').append('Success!');
        },
    }).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data) {
        $('#upload_file_start').click(function() {
            jqXHR = data.submit();
        });
        $('#cancelBtn').click(function(e) {
            jqXHR.abort();
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a cancel upload button to jquery-file-upload basic-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218571/how-to-add-a-cancel-upload-button-to-jquery-file-upload-basic-plugin)

Comment: Please also add some code of your files for we can take a look

Comment: Code has been added